# EXCEL VBA - Function that retrun array

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to build function in VBA that build an array and return it to array that's in another sub so I can use this function in multiple places.
For example:

```
Sub getArrayData ()
 Dim myItemsArr() As String ' dynamic array
 myItemsArr = functionToFillArray
End sub
```

And let's assume this is the function

```
Function functionToFillArray(arrayIWantToFill as Variant) 
 arrayToFill = ("A","B","C")
 arrayIWantToFill  = ???
 functionToFillArray = ?? ' what should i do here to return the array i want to fill
End function
```

At other language suck as Java its more clear to me how to do it, but in VBA I just don't understand how its work yet.
I try to find some information online, but without success

Comment: It's not really clear what you want your function to do.  Your two bocks of code are not in agreement.  Your sub passes no argument to the function, but the function expects one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Function getArrayData() As Variant

    Dim myItemsArr As Variant

    ' Fill array.
    functionToFillArray myItemsArr

    getArrayData = myItemsArr

End Function


Sub functionToFillArray(arrayIWantToFill As Variant) 

    arrayIWantToFill = Array("A","B","C")
 
End Sub
```